# How do you check if a ListView contains a specified header?

Tags: android, listview

I've tried using the ListView.indexOfChild(View view) method to check if the ListView contains a specified header view, but sometimes it returns -1 when the ListView actually does contain a specified header. Is there a better way to check for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If by 'header' you mean an actual header added using either of the [`addHeaderView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) methods, you can simply retrieve the number of added headers using [`getHeaderViewsCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getHeaderViewsCount%28%29).

Alternatively, if I remember correctly, `ListView` will wrap its adapter inside a [`HeaderViewListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html) if it contains headers and/or footers. You can use its [`getHeadersCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html#getHeadersCount%28%29) to retrieve the same number as above.

---

**Edit:** If you want to check whether a specific header is added, you should be able to query the `HeaderViewListAdapter` for that. You will need some sort of criteria to check against.

For example, if there are 3 headers in your `ListView`, you can iterate over the first three items (you can probably grab them either directly from the `HeaderListViewAdapter`, or use the `ListView`'s `getItemAtPosition(...)` method) and see if one matches the criteria. The easiest way to do this 'matching' is probably to add headers using the `addHeaderView(...)` method that also takes an `Object` parameter. You can supply basically anything to differentiate between the multiple headers, obviously provided that the data objects are different. E.g. you could just pass in a String.

With this data in place, you can call `getItem(...)`/`getItemAtPosition(...)` for the first 3 positions and check what gets returned. The benefit of using a String for data is that every Java object implements a `toString()` method, which you can then exploit for a straightforward `.equals(..)` comparison.

Alternatively, you could use reflection to get ahold of the actual `mHeaderViewInfos` member variable (which is just an `ArrayList<ListView.FixedViewInfo>`) and use that for the conditional logic.

Comment: Cool I didn't know about that method, useful to know. However, some of my ListViews will contain multiple headers. Is there a way I can tell if they contain a specific header?

Comment: Right, I actually could've picked that up from the question title. Anyways, please see the addition to my original answer. That should help you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the updated response. That sounds like a good way to go about it. Alternatively, I've taken the very simple approach of setting a boolean flag 'headerXAdded' to true whenever I call addHeaderView(v) and clearing that flag whenever I remove the header view.